# T-SQL request execution runs into timeout if execution time is much longer than prior execution

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a T-SQL request whose execution time sometimes is very short and sometimes very long depending on the given parameters in its where-condition.

If the very first execution takes only a short time all following long-running executions run into a timeout exception

> "Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation".

If I clear the cache by executing this...

```
DBCC FreeProcCache
DBCC DropCleanbuffers
```

... and execute a long-running request at first all further request run successfully.

What is the mechanism behind this behaviour? And how can I stop sql server from terminating long-running requests?

Comment: You probably want to read up on [parameter sniffing](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/06/the-elephant-and-the-mouse-or-parameter-sniffing-in-sql-server/) and how to prevent it from producing pathological execution plans.

Comment: SQL Server does not terminate queries nor does it have a timeout. That's coming from somewhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're seeing what's known as Parameter Sniffing. Basically, the optimizer is building the execution plan based upon the first parameters it encounters. This plan may not be great for other parameters though. You could look into OPTION (RECOMPILE) as this will rebuild the execution plan each time you run the code.

Check out the link below for an explanation;

https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/06/the-elephant-and-the-mouse-or-parameter-sniffing-in-sql-server/